# Override a specific url in codeigniter htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, cron

Currently I have a codeigniter project which has the following .htaccess and is working as expected.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]    
</IfModule>
```

I have a function site.com/cron/parsexml which runs correctly when used as a URI. I'd like to add it as a CRON job. I've tried the command line "php index.php cron parsexml" which doesn't work (couldn't figure out what is wrong with that though). So I was hoping I'd put a direct  URL like site.com/cron.html and use .htaccess to get it rewritten. But I'm not able to do that. 
Tried the following which is not working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^cron.*
RewriteRule ^cron.html$ index.php/cron/parsexml [L,QSA]
```

Thanks for looking into.

Comment: Though I did not get a solution for the above, I used "curl site.com/cron/parsexml" for the cron job and my actual problem is solved. Would really appreciate if anybody could provide a solution for the above.

Answer (score 3):

Try with full path to index.php, example:

```
php /home/username/www/index.php cron parsexml
```